# Price of a Forward Contract

Tags: stochastic-calculus, forward

I have the following,

> Let ${F_t,t\geq0}$ be the price process of the forward contract on the
> risky asset with maturity $T' > 0$. Since interest rates are
> deterministic, we have
>
> $$F_t=S_t\ e^{r(T^\prime-t)}\ =F_0\ e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t+\sigma B_t}$$

Why do we have $-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t+\sigma B_t$ in the exponent? Where did it come from? If the price of the underlying $S_t$ is stochastic, why don't we have a stochastic term in the middle equation $S_t\ e^{r(T^\prime-t)}$?

Comment: In the BS model, we assume $dS=rSdt+\sigma SdB_t$. Itô’s Lemma implies $S_t=S_0e^{\left(r-0.5\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma B_t}$. That’s just true if the stock price follows a geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: Once you substitute $S_t$ with the expression KeSchn gave, and then rewrite $S_0$ in terms of $F_0$ you will have your result.

Comment: Where is this proposition taken from please? Does it mention conditioning/filtration etc ?